# How to load an assets based on custom field value?

Tags: custom-field, wp-admin, post-meta, wp-enqueue-script, performance

How can I load an asset based on custom field value?

- This would be outside of the loop, all I can find for this is in the loop related functions, which I'm not familiar with, or what I find are articles related to the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

I would like something like this... which I think is most logical for what I am trying to do, but obviously this doesn't exist, at least in this format. But the code below itself should help clarify what I am trying to if my description doesn't.

```
if ( custom_field( 'field_name', 'field_value' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style-here' );
}
```

[image: My Custom Field Screenshot]

The closest article I can find is @ http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/#highlighter_361592

But since I don't know the loop it just throws me off because I don't see where I would place my custom field value, not just the custom field name.

I want to do this for performance reasons, so I can load some layout css only if that layout is actually used.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: As i look further, maybe I'm looking for some wrong information. Maybe I'm looking for the "key" and "value"? Is the key equal to the custom field name and the value equal to the custom field value?Reading that out load I think I just answered that. But will dig a little more.

Comment: You would want to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, and within there, instead of `custom_field` you would do `global $post; $layout = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'layout', true ); if( $layout == ...  )`

Comment: follow @czerspalace direction. Btw, WordPress doesn't have any `custom_field()` function.

Comment: @czerspalace thanks for this! Appreciate it. 

Maybe you can answer the post so I can give it a point or approve the answer? I'm still a bit new to it, but I don't want to answer it myself, because I didn't create the answer.

Comment: @sisir thanks. Yeah, I found that out. Would this be a good idea to have though? It seems more simple and straight forward for cases like this. I not a pro, but if it seems useful that Wordpress could add, I would take the time to submit it. Let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action, and within there, instead of `custom_field` you would use `get_post_meta`, like this:

```
function wpse217823_enqueue_per_custom_field(){
    global $post; 
    $layout = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'layout', true ); 
    if( $layout == ... ){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-custom-style-here' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse217823_enqueue_per_custom_field' );
```